# Instance of '_Future<dynamic>' instead of input value in Translator package from Flutter

Tags: flutter, input, flutter-packages, translators, flutter-future

this scope gives me Instance of **_Future** but I want to get that translated text.

```
Future<dynamic> translate(String input) async {
final translator = GoogleTranslator();
var result;
var translation = await translator
    .translate(input, to: 'tr')
    .then((value) => {result = value});
  return result;
}
```

Comment: how did you try to access the value returned from the function?

Comment: ' var result = arabicBuyer.translate("sentence"); print(result.toString()); ' @X2

Comment: translate returns a Future so you will need to wait for the result. Either use await keyword like this  var result = await arabicBuyer.translate("sentence"); or use .then like so arabicBuyer.translate("sentence").then((result) => print(result));

Comment: thanks. this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I guess the `.translate` function returns an `Translate` instance. You need the `text` attribute to get a `String`

Below code is wrong!

```
Future<String> translate(String input) async {
  final translator = GoogleTranslator();
  var result;
  var translation = await translator
      .translate(input, to: 'tr')
      .then((value) => {result = value});
  return result.text;
}
```

Also you use a `then` clause and getting the result of translation in to `value` so you don't need to use `await` and set the var `translation` in this case. Or you can use `await` and remove the `then`. But you should not use both `await` and `then` for the same async method.

So the below code should be used:

```
Future<String> translate(String input) async {
  final translator = GoogleTranslator();
  var translation = await translator
      .translate(input, to: 'tr');
  return translation.text;
}
```

Comment: The scope that you mentioned seems not right at least doesn't fit to my code. I get same error except <String>.